# How to output npm build error log files from linux hosted agents in vsts?

Tags: linux, npm, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Trying to use the Linux build agents on vsts to build an angular application. For some reason it fails on the agent and I would like to get the full details in the log files. Any examples on how to get that sent to the output from the hosted build agents in vsts using a vsts build task?

[image: vsts build agent error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the log files from Hosted agent, you just need to add **Copy Files task** and **Publish Build Artifacts task** in your build definition. Detail steps as below:

1. Add Copy Files task after the task you failed

   After the task you failed (as the failed log you showed), add Copy Files task with below settings:

   [image]
   [image]
2. Add Publish Build Artifacts task after Copy Files task

   The Publish Build Artifacts task settings as below:

   [image]
   [image]
3. Queue the build agent again

   After the build finished, download the build artifacts to get the log files:

   [image]